# Delete Report Folder From Managed Package

Tags: community, managed-package, custom-reports

We have managed package with custom Reports. We are planning to clean up some folders. Will it be a problem if report folder is deleted from Managed package which is already added in package earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components), you are able to delete Reports and Folders from Managed Package without contacting Salesforce support for enabling ability to remove components for your packaging org.

But

> A developer can delete some components after the package is uploaded as Managed - Released. **Deleted components are not deleted in the subscriber's org during a package upgrade.**